# Python and Python3 Configuration on Raspbian ImportError No Module Named Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspbian

on each Python Module I tried to import in Python or Python3 on my Raspberry Pi I got the error ImportError: No module named [module_name]. As example I got this error:

```
ImportError: No module named sense_emu
```

If I try this code:

```
from sense_emu import SenseHat
```

The problem is not the SenseHat. My problem is the whole python configuration. The SenseHat module is installed. I got the same problems if I want to import TensorFlow or OpenCV (cv2) modules. Both libraries are also installed. Also ROS is installed. It seems like Python in general can`t import Modules.

Comment: Are you sure you run `python3` and not `python`? The latter is mapped to Python 2.7 on Raspbian and other Debian variants.

Answer (score 0):

try

> from sense_hat import SenseHat